# How do I export a list of email addresses from an email in Outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, export

I have a list of email addresses in an email in Outlook 2007 I want to export. If I select them in the 'to' field and copy and paste them all, all I get are the names rather than the email addresses.

How can I get a list of the email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [Save Email Addresses](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSave/) utility for that. Just install it, select the required message(s) in your Outlook and use the right-click menu to run the tool. You'll get all email addresses in the resulting list.

Please note: I recommend this tools because I'm one of its developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Jon, I'm not sure if OL2007 behaves the same, but in OL2013 if you select, copy, and paste into Notepad or Word, Outlook appends addresses to the result, in a semicolon-separated list format.

For example:

> Runner, Road; Mouse, Mickey

..pastes in Notepad to:

> Runner, Road <rr@wb.us>; Mouse, Mickey <mm@disney.channel>

Whereas, if pasted into a new envelope the address may be concealed.